# Unable to permanently delete Azure DevOps Server 2020 project

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-devops-server

I deleted two projects in Azure DevOps Server 2020 using the collection settings -> projects screen. I know DevOps Server soft deletes projects and they are listed when you click on 'View recently deleted projects'.

I want to permanently delete the two projects. I've tried deleting the two projects using Azure CLI with the command `az devops project delete --id [project id]` and I keep getting the error `VS800075: The project with id '8f0d8b14-837b-47aa-802c-aac2*********' does not exist, or you do not have permission to access it.` I've tried inputting the id without dashes and get the same error.

I've tried to use [TFSDeleteProject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/command-line/tfsdeleteproject-cmd?view=azure-devops-2020) but it's not available with my version of Visual Studio, 2022. I think it might be only available with older versions.

I've also tried to delete the two projects using the Azure DevOps REST Api and I get a similar error:

```
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"VS800075: The project with id
     | '8f0d8b14-837b-47aa-802c-*************' does not exist, or you do not have permission to access
     | it.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.ProjectDoesNotExistException,
     | Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi","typeKey":"ProjectDoesNotExistException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
```

I've regenerated my security token in DevOps and made sure I have full permissions. Is there a way to permanently delete a project in DevOps Server 2020?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to wait 28 days until it will permanently deleted you need to delete the project from the **Azure DevOps Administration Console**:

[image]

Comment: That worked! Thanks.